# Wrap withCredentials step and provide context

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with my Shared Library. I wrote a context manager to provide me the steps object. Therefore I wrote a wrapping class for the steps object, to make it easier to unittest my code. I managed to wrap nearly every step I need with the exception of the `withCredentials` step. I don't know how to get the context to my closure. Here is the relevant code of my current impelementation:

```
// StepExecutor.groovy
class StepExecutor implements IStepExecutor {
    private def _steps

    StepExecutor(steps) {
        _steps = steps
    }

    @Override
    void withCredentials(List bindings, Closure closure) {
        this._steps.withCredentials(bindings, closure)
    }

    @Override
    def usernamePassword(Map credentials) {
        return this._steps.usernamePassword(credentials)
    }
}
```

```
// SomeFile.groovy
steps.withCredentials([
        steps.usernamePassword(
                credentialsId: "Sharepoint365",
                passwordVariable: "pass",
                usernameVariable: "user"
        )
]) {
// Do something with pass and user
}
```

The corresponding code is `withCredentials` where I pass the closure, which is executed and in which I'd like to have the `pass` and `user` variables set. How can I accomplish that? I tried to solve it looking at the code here https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-binding-plugin but I must admit, that I have no clue about what they are doing there.

I know I could call withCredentials directly on the object, but I'd like to wrap it, but I see this solution as my last option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, why the direct access to `pass` and `user` wasn't possible. The variables are stored in the steps object itself (maybe even the env?) therefore I had to access these variables via the steps object.
Therefore I wrote a function, which invokes `steps.<name>` like this:

```
// StepExecutor.groovy
class StepExecutor implements IStepExecutor {
    ...

    @Override
    String get(String name) {
        return this._steps."${name}"
    }
}
```

And to access these I just called `StepExecutor.get("pass/user")` inside my closure.